# How can I set a mongoose schema so that it can be only modified once?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

so I am building this bidding app, the mongoose schema of that particular app look something like this

```
const bidSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    name: String,
    price : Number,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    specilization: String,
    image: String,
    highestBidder: {
      highBidderName: String,
      highPrice: Number,
     },
     previousBidders: [{previousName: String , previousPrice: Number}],
     isClosed: {
       type: Boolean,
     }
     
})
```

in the schema above, the value for isClosed will be remained none, and if the person closed the bidding , I will set a true value for that isClosed variable and do operations accordingly.
the problem here is that the security part of it, like any person can actually send a put request in the edit field of that form using something like postman,
with the value like

```
isClosed : false
```

, it is getting updated. is there any thing I can do about this so that the user can only set the false value for it and once it is set, no one should be able to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Approaches towards this -

- **Most Commonly used** - You can do a findOne({**YOUR_UNIQUE_KEY: SOME_VALUE**}) , add a condition in your code if **isClosed : true** - throw Error else Do your Operation
- Since you are building a bidding APP, you should expect High Concurrency. You can try this **db.insertIfNotExistsDemo** , you could check it here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/insert-records-in-mongodb-collection-if-it-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be: retrieve your bid from database, check if value of `isCloses == true` if not make the update.

```js
Bid.findOne({ name }, function (err, bid) {
    if(bid.isClosed) {
      console.error('Bid is closed')
    };

    bid.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
    });
});
```